# Angular Material Component schematics

Tags: angular, angular-material, components, angular-cli, angular-schematics

Whenever I run this command `ng generate @angular/material:navigation dashboard` the terminal shows this

> The 'path' option in '__\Desktop\machine test\employee\node_modules@angular\material\schematics\ng-generate\navigation\schema.json' is using deprecated behaviour. 'workingDirectory' smart default provider should be used instead.(0 , validation_1.validateName) is not a function

Is there another way to implement schematics in my project...:)

I tried this:

```
"$default": {
  "$source": "projectName"
}
```

in path of `schema.json`

Deprecated behavior problem solved but the 'validation is not a function' still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that the version of `@angular-devkit/schematics-cli` you're using is a newer version than the version of `@angular/materials` you're using, which is why you're seeing this message.

---

Previously when defining the "path" property in a schematic you would do the following in the `schema.json` for the schematic definition:

```json
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "path",
      "description": "The path at which to create .README directory and files",
      "visible": false
    }
  }
}
```

When the schematic was run if no "path" arg was supplied a default would be correctly set.

This can be seen in the 13.0.x version the the [angular material dashboard schematic](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/13.0.x/src/material/schematics/ng-generate/dashboard/schema.json)

---

As the error suggests (although unless you know schematics it's admittedly not very helpful) the "path" definition needed to be updated to:

```json
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "path",
      "description": "The path at which to create .README directory and files",
      "visible": false,
      "$default": {
        "$source": "workingDirectory"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen in the 14.0.x version the the [angular material dashboard schematic](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/14.0.x/src/material/schematics/ng-generate/dashboard/schema.json)

---

`"workingDirectory"` as the error suggests is a 'smart default provider' that sets the default value of the path.

`"projectName"` is also a 'smart default provider' but it sets the default value as the project name, not the current path.